# Vinder: Stack Exchange Voting Tinder (Placeholder)

Tags: app, placeholder

Placeholder, suggestion by [Simon Forsberg](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/31562/simon-forsberg).

The purpose of this application is to allow a more convenient method of voting on Stack Exchange posts, while creating a shuffle and supporting lower-reputation users to facilitate community engagement.

A, somewhat secret, beta version of this is currently in testing and will be included here soon.

Comment: This was flagged as a stale placeholder. See [this answer](https://stackapps.com/a/7591) for more information.